# Spring MVC REST + OAuth & CSRF

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to build a REST service with Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and running into a number of issues.

**Issue #1**

I am unable to turn off CSRF when testing. This means that my POST-only '/users/register' mapping requires a CSRF token. It should not be required and indeed you cannot get a token because only POST is valid here.
The other test configuration files work.
Running the server using Spring Boot uses my production configuration which disables CSRF. The production configuration which disables csrf is run when testing as confirmed by setting a breakpoint on it.

**Issue #2**

Enabling 2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter classes (1 for production, 1 for test overrides) with the correct @Order(n) annotation seems to revert the MVC back to HTML forms rather than REST e.g. instead of getting 401 responses to requests when unauthenticated I am getting 302.

**Issue #3**

Giving up on the configuration and manually adding the CSRF token in the test does not work either. I still get "**Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?**" This is my test:

```java
    String registrationRequest = this.json(new RegistrationRequest("Robin", "Elvin", "robinelvin", "robpass"));
    CsrfToken csrfToken = httpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(new MockHttpServletRequest());
    mockMvc.perform(post("/users/register")
                    .header(csrfToken.getHeaderName(), csrfToken.getToken())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(contentType)
            .content(registrationRequest)
    ).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

So I am going round in circles on this and have spent all day trying to get a simple test working. I cannot find any documentation on how you are supposed to set up and test what I am trying to achieve.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?